# r plotly set global option for modebarButtons

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

Creating a plotly object of a ggplot object. Is it possible to set the modebar options globally so each plotly plot displays only the following modebarButtons as in myPlot_c.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


myPlot_a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) + geom_point()
myPlot_b <- ggplotly(myPlot_a)

#Is it possible to set this global, so don't have to repeat for each plot
myPlot_c <- myPlot_b %>% 
  config(displaylogo=F,
         modeBarButtonsToRemove = 
           list("sendDataToCloud","zoom2d","pan2d","select2d","lasso2d",
                "zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","autoScale2d","hoverClosestCartesian",
                "hoverCompareCartesian"))
```

I could wrap in a function, but have found that using in conjunction with a shiny app the renderPlotly() suffers a lot of lag if the modebarButtons are set each time.

Comment: out of curiosity, are your buttons actually being removed with this code. it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Worked for me (plotly 4.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to define a custom wrapper

```r
library(ggplot2)

clean_ggplotly <- function(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = "all",
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,
  source = "A",
  ...
) {

  stopifnot(requireNamespace("plotly"))

  plotly::config(
    plotly::ggplotly(
      p = p,
      width = width,
      height = height,
      tooltip = tooltip,
      dynamicTicks = dynamicTicks,
      layerData = layerData,
      originalData = originalData,
      source = source,
      ... = ...
    ),
    displaylogo = FALSE,
    modeBarButtonsToRemove = c(
      "sendDataToCloud",
      "zoom2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d",
      "pan2d", "select2d", "lasso2d", "autoScale2d",
      "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian"
    )
  )
}


gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

clean_ggplotly(gg)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to specify the package from which config is coming from :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


myPlot_a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) + geom_point()
myPlot_b <- ggplotly(myPlot_a)

#Is it possible to set this global, so don't have to repeat for each plot
myPlot_c <- myPlot_b %>% 
  plotly::config(displaylogo=F,
         modeBarButtonsToRemove = 
           list("sendDataToCloud","zoom2d","pan2d","select2d","lasso2d",
                "zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","autoScale2d","hoverClosestCartesian",
                "hoverCompareCartesian"))
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanations, for more guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer